# Using constants as default parameter values in interfaces: IDE okay but mxmlc fails?

Tags: actionscript-3, interface, constants

This code seems to compile fine in the IDE, but the command-line compiler (SDK 4.5 mxmlc.exe) reports "Parameter initializer unknown or is not a compile-time constant."

[senocular](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/compilererrors/#1047) gives a good explanation and a maybe-workaround, but I'm hoping for something more elegent (like a command-line instruction).

```
package {
    public class Constants {
        public static const CONSTANT : int = 0;
    }
}


package {
    public interface IInterface {
            function foo( param : int = Constants.CONSTANT ) : void;
    }
}

package
{
    public class Concrete implements IInterface
    {   
            public function foo(param:int=Constants.CONSTANT):void
            {        
            }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you could try configuration constants? http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to create your own batch type script to pre-process the source before the compiler gets it, but that's probably not the best idea. It would work, though, assuming you got all the bugs out :)

Answer (score 2):

According to Senocular, it's all about the compilation order. There's no explicit way to set this order.

You could define inline constants using the [*define*](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html) compiler option to avoid this problem.

Another way would be to create a library containing the constants. Libraries are included before user classes.
To create a library use the [component compiler](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html#246171):

```
compc -output lib\Constants.swf -source-path src -include-classes Constants
```

When compiling the application, include that library:

```
mxmlc -include-libraries lib\Constants.swf -- src\Main.as
```

Just don't forget to recompile the library when the constants change, or use a build script that takes care of that.

---

A short comment on the example code:
The interface doesn't need to use that constant, any value will do and have the same effect on implementing classes.

[Programming AS3 - Interfaces](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f41.html)

> A method that implements such a function declaration must have a default parameter value that is a member of the same data type as the value specified in the interface definition, but the actual value does not have to match.